# Установка библиотек .whl без интернета

Tags: python

Cтолкнулся с трудностью установки библиотеки на сервер. Установка через pip невозможна политиками Proxy. Устанавливал библиотеки через скачивание .whl файлов, но с библиотекой Apscheduler не получилось. При установке, все равно пытается выйти в сеть. Можно как либо это обойти?

[image: screenshot is bagger]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всем кто столкнется с такой же проблемой, решил вопрос отдельным скачиванием и установкой не достающих библиотек, ошибка укажет на то, какой библиотеки не хватает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачал с pypi.org библиотеку (.whl), установил, через pip install 'название библиотеки.whl' - и все заработало.